# App crashes when starting Activity

Tags: android

I have been searching online for hours, but to no avail.

I have been working on an app that switches to different layouts depending on the screen resolution, but whenever I try to start the new Activity, the app crashes...

This is my MainActivity, where the new class is called from:

```
package com.example.mywallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int width = 0;
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

        w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

        width = size.x;
    } else {
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        width = d.getWidth();
    }
    switch (width) {
    case 480:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Your screen width is " + width,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                FourEightyEightHundred.class));
        break;
    case 720:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Your screen width is " + width,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }

}
}
```

This is the AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mywallpapers"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mywallpapers.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FourEightyEightHundred"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mywallpapers.FOUREIGHT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And the Activity that is called:

```
package com.example.mywallpapers;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class FourEightyEightHundred extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView display;
int toPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.foureightyeighthundred);        

    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP1);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP2);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP3);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP4);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP5);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP6);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP7);
    ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP8);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP9);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP10);
    ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP11);
    ImageView image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP12);
    ImageView image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP13);
    ImageView image13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP14);
    ImageView image14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP15);
    ImageView image15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP16);
    ImageView image16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP17);
    ImageView image17 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP18);
    ImageView image18 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP19);
    ImageView image19 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP20);
    ImageView image20 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP21);
    ImageView image21 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP22);
    ImageView image22 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP23);
    ImageView image23 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP24);
    ImageView image24 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP25);
    ImageView image25 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP26);
    ImageView image26 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP27);
    ImageView image27 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP28);
    ImageView image28 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP29);
    ImageView image29 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP30);
    ImageView image30 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP31);
    Button setWallPaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetWallPaperButton);       

    toPhone = R.drawable.foureightyone;

    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    image5.setOnClickListener(this);
    image6.setOnClickListener(this);
    image7.setOnClickListener(this);
    image8.setOnClickListener(this);
    image9.setOnClickListener(this);
    image10.setOnClickListener(this);
    image11.setOnClickListener(this);
    image12.setOnClickListener(this);
    image13.setOnClickListener(this);
    image14.setOnClickListener(this);
    image15.setOnClickListener(this);
    image16.setOnClickListener(this);
    image17.setOnClickListener(this);
    image18.setOnClickListener(this);
    image19.setOnClickListener(this);
    image20.setOnClickListener(this);
    image21.setOnClickListener(this);
    image22.setOnClickListener(this);
    image23.setOnClickListener(this);
    image24.setOnClickListener(this);
    image25.setOnClickListener(this);
    image26.setOnClickListener(this);
    image27.setOnClickListener(this);
    image28.setOnClickListener(this);
    image29.setOnClickListener(this);
    image30.setOnClickListener(this);
    setWallPaper.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.WaP2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.foureightytwo);
        toPhone = R.drawable.foureightytwo;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.foureightythree);
        toPhone = R.drawable.foureightythree;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.foureightyfour);
        toPhone = R.drawable.foureightyfour;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP5:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.foureightyfive);
        toPhone = R.drawable.foureightyfive;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP6:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.foureightysix);
        toPhone = R.drawable.foureightysix;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP7:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.fortyeightyseven);
        toPhone = R.drawable.fortyeightyseven;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP8:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.aardbeien);
        toPhone = R.drawable.aardbeien;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP9:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
        toPhone = R.drawable.android;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP10:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bloemetje_gras_lucht);
        toPhone = R.drawable.bloemetje_gras_lucht;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP11:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bloemetje);
        toPhone = R.drawable.bloemetje;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP12:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.druppel_op_blad);
        toPhone = R.drawable.druppel_op_blad;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP13:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.duin_lucht);
        toPhone = R.drawable.duin_lucht;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP14:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.frambozen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.frambozen;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP15:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.duin_lucht);
        toPhone = R.drawable.duin_lucht;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP16:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.gras_lucht);
        toPhone = R.drawable.gras_lucht;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP17:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.jelly_beans);
        toPhone = R.drawable.jelly_beans;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP18:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.katje);
        toPhone = R.drawable.katje;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP19:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.kerstballen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.kerstballen;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP20:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.lieveheersbeestje);
        toPhone = R.drawable.lieveheersbeestje;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP21:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.pinguins);
        toPhone = R.drawable.pinguins;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP22:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.roze_paarse_bloemetjes);
        toPhone = R.drawable.roze_paarse_bloemetjes;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP23:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.roze_panterprint);
        toPhone = R.drawable.roze_panterprint;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP24:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.roze_rozen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.roze_rozen;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP25:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.stand_zee);
        toPhone = R.drawable.stand_zee;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP26:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.stenen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.stenen;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP27:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.stro_rol);
        toPhone = R.drawable.stro_rol;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP28:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.tijger);
        toPhone = R.drawable.tijger;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP29:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.tulpen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.tulpen;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP30:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.watermannetje);
        toPhone = R.drawable.watermannetje;
        break;
    case R.id.WaP31:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wolf);
        toPhone = R.drawable.wolf;
        break;
    case R.id.SetWallPaperButton:
        Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(toPhone));
            try{
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(whatever);
                }
            catch( IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper set!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    }

}
```

And the LogCat

```
    05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mywallpapers/com.example.mywallpapers.FourEightyEightHundred}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #103: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #103: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at com.example.mywallpapers.FourEightyEightHundred.onCreate(FourEightyEightHundred.java:28)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     ... 11 more
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     ... 26 more
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
    05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>    (ImageView.java:110)
    05-06 21:52:41.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1097):     ... 29 more
```

And the layout xml for the activity that I want to start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/kiezen" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/WaP1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
        android:src="@drawable/foureightyone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SetWallPaperButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/WaP1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ZetKnop" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollWallPapers"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/SetWallPaperButton"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="156dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/foureightytwo" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP3"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/foureightythree" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP4"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/foureightyfour" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP5"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/foureightyfive" />        
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP6"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/foureightysix" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP7"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/fortyeightyseven" />        
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP8"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/aardbeien" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP9"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/android" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP10"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/bloemetje_gras_lucht" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP11"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/bloemetje" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP12"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/druppel_op_blad" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP13"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/duin_lucht" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP14"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/frambozen" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP15"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/gekleurde_bellen" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP16"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/gras_lucht" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP17"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/jelly_beans" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP18"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/katje" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP19"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/kerstballen" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP20"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/lieveheersbeestje" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP21"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/pinguins" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP22"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/roze_paarse_bloemetjes" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP23"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/roze_panterprint" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP24"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/roze_rozen" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP25"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/stand_zee" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP26"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/stenen" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP27"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/stro_rol" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP28"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/tijger" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP29"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/tulpen" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP30"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/watermannetje" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WaP31"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Display"
                android:src="@drawable/wolf" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the stack trace/ logcat output of the crash

Comment: You really need to post the stack trace but it is probably about calling finish() from a thread that is not the UI thread. If you want to close the activity from the logoTimer thread you need a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Since you deleted the misplaced finish() and are still having trouble, post your logcat!

Comment: What is at line 28 of `FourEightyEightHundred`? And maybe post that xml file

Comment: line 28 of the Class is    setContentView(R.layout.foureightyeighthundred);
and I will post the xml file for the 480 res as well

Comment: Seems that your layout file has some mistake. Like @devconsole said: your bitmaps are crashing your app.

Comment: How large are the bitmaps you are trying to load?

Comment: the bitmaps (all in .png format) are between 75 and 200kb each

Comment: You have 30 images and a maximum of anywhere between 16 to 64 MB available in the process, depending on the device. You have to consider the decoded size per image not the compressed size, that is 4 bytes per pixel. You should probably use a ListView because it is capable of freeing and reusing views, so you'll only allocate what's visible on the screen (plus one or two views maybe).

Comment: See also [How much memory does each android process get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747211).

Comment: I see... Thanks, I will look into the ListView way to show the images. @DigCamara, yes, there were some errors in the .xml file, some invalid layout params, so I fixed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to delete the finish() method and reduce the amount of required CPU within the page. I replaced the images with buttons and that helped ;)