# OutOfMemoryException far from memory limit

Tags: android, memory, opengl-es

In my application I use quite a lot of assets to render. This caused my application to crash with an exception indicating that there is no more memory left (when allocating a byte array). Using meminfo I've seen that my process uses about 40mb of memory which according to my calculations is correct (so no hidden excessive memory allocation in my code).

The total memory usage on my system is 300mb. My tablet however supports 1gb of memory and I wonder why it throws me an exception at a usage of 300mb. Is there some per process limit that I need to change? Or are there any other things I'm missing about androids memory management?

Comment: without code how one can help you. People are not god dude

Comment: try add largeheap = true in manifest file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10747242/1939564

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia: The question was not related to code but to the general concept of memory allocation, hence no godly powers required to get the information i suppose.

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn if the heap is large there will be more frequent gc and more pause times http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. the guy in the video gives a big warning . so you should carefully use large heap

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn & Muhammad Babar: Thanks, that indeed helped me getting it to work! Though even with 128mb of memory im a bit disappointet that im unable to allocate any new memory even with over 50% of my tablets memory unused...

Comment: @Muepe hey added as answer to close this thread accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to androidManifest in application tag

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to make things work but this will consume more memory hence more gc calls

Comment: By adding this tag to your manifest.xml, be sure about that your build target must be Android 3.0 (API 11) or above. Otherwise, it will not work!