# when Executing AsyncTask its giving out of memory error

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

i am trying to run an existing project of android.its giving error trace

```
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:71)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:54)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache.open(DiskLruCache.java:226)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.hercules.quantum.QuantumActivity$InitThumbnailDiskCacheTask.doInBackground(QuantumActivity.java:5575)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.hercules.quantum.QuantumActivity$InitThumbnailDiskCacheTask.doInBackground(QuantumActivity.java:1)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-14 22:49:14.812: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  ... 4 more
```

and the source code related to which its showing this error is

```
class InitThumbnailDiskCacheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            synchronized (thumbnailLruCacheLock) {
                // Check if media is mounted or storage is built-in, if so, try and use external cache dir
                // otherwise use internal cache dir
                final String cachePath =
                        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
                                !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() ? getExternalCacheDir().getPath() :
                                        getCacheDir().getPath();
                                Log.i("Cache Path","Cache Path"+cachePath);

                try {
                    if (!isCancelled()) {
                        thumbnailLruCache = DiskLruCache.open(
                                new File(cachePath + File.separator + "thumbnails"),
                                APP_VERSION,
                                VALUE_COUNT,
                                DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initialize thumbnail cahce", e);
                }
                thumbnailLruCacheStarting = false; // Finished initialization
                thumbnailLruCacheLock.notifyAll(); // Wake any waiting threads
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

can anyone please guide line how to resolve it.

Comment: Which is the 226th line of your DiskLruCache.java file?

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/disklrucache/DiskLruCache.java this is the library

Comment: main issue in  Log.i("Cache Path","Cache Path"+cachePath); this log is not showing in LogCat

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating too much memory. In Android, processes are given a limited amount of memory (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747211/how-much-memory-does-each-android-process-get)) and the total of your process memory cannot exceed that or you'll get an `OutOfMemoryError`. Consider splitting your loading in several steps so GC can free unused memory.