# Android: why is memory usage for one application drasmatically larger than allowable memory for one process

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

As I researched, Android allocates limit memory for each process, maybe range from 16MB to 24MB for each one. Here is [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747211/how-much-memory-does-each-android-process-get)

Nevertheless when I view memory usage for one application in setting, I often see one normal application costs hundred megabytes for memory (on one process). There is a conflict here that I cannot understand.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NDK code can use more system RAM than can a single Dalvik/ART process. Also, the app might be using more than one process, or it might be using `android:largeHeap` to request an above-normal heap size.

Comment: my own app also uses hundred megabytes. Although I don't use native memory or `android:largeHeap` option.

Comment: so are there any other reasons?

Comment: @TrầnKimDự: Libraries that you use might use NDK code, more than one process, or request `android:largeHeap` (though the latter two would be bad form, IMHO). Also, bear in mind that there is more to your process than just memory that you allocate. Depending on how you are measuring this stuff, you may be associated with a portion of the memory consumed by the core zygote process that all apps are forked from. Do not use Settings as a guide for memory consumption. Use [developer tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html) instead.

Comment: thanks. I will try this tool for investigating my memory usage :"D